# C question in logical OR: 2 operands evaluated (0) false, but the result works as TRUE range

Tags: operator-overloading, expression

My doubt is about the basic theory of "or logical operator". Especifically, logical OR returns true only if either one operand is true.

For instance, in this OR expression (x<O || x> 8) using x=5 when I evalute the 2 operand, I interpret it as both of them are false.

But I have an example that does not fit wiht it rule. On the contrary the expression works as range between 0 and 8, both included.
Following the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
    { 
    int x ; //This is the variable for being evaluated 
    do 
    { 
    printf("Imput a figure between 1 and 8 : "); 
    scanf("%i", &x);
    }
    while ( x < 1 ||  x > 8);  // Why this expression write in this way determinate the range???
    {
    printf("Your imput was ::: %d ",x);
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

I have modified my first question. I really appreciate any helpo in order to clarify my doubt

In advance, thank you very much. Otto

Comment: Logical OR is actually evaluate first expression, if true, return true, if false, evaluate second expression. Apply logic again.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, in spite of both operands evaluate false, the result of the expression is true

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `while` loop; it's a `do` ... `while` loop. The formatting makes it hard to see. Reformatted:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) { 
    int x;

    // Execute the code in the `do { }` block once, no matter what.
    // Keep executing it again and again, so long as the condition
    // in `while ( )` is true.
    do { 
        printf("Imput a figure between 1 and 8 : "); 
        scanf("%i", &x);
    } while (x < 1 ||  x > 8);

    // This creates a new scope. While perfectly valid C,
    // this does absolutely nothing in this particular case here.
    {
        printf("Your imput was ::: %d ",x);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The block with the two `printf` calls is *not* part of the loop. The `while (x < 1 ||  x > 8)` makes it so that the code in the `do { }` block runs, *so long as* `x < 1` or `x > 8`. In other words, it runs *until* `x` is between `1` and `8`. This has the effect of asking the user to input a number again and again, until they finally input a number that's between `1` and `8`.